# What does scalaz.syntax.std.OptionOps.cata do in scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Here is a [description](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.syntax.std.OptionOps) about cata function from scalaz. But what is a purpose og using this function? By the way is there a scaladoc for scalaz with description, not only code.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as `fold` on `scala.Option`: it lets you map both the has-a-value branch and the empty branch into a single result value.  Anywhere you might see

```
Option(x) match {
  case Some(y) => f(y)
  case None => y0
}
```

you can use `fold` on `Option` or `cata` on scalaz' variant instead.

(Note: for this particular case, pattern matching is typically more efficient, but not always more convenient.)

Comment: As I understand there should be also implicit Monoid object when call cata,  is it?